# Synchronizing Data in Python (or Excel)

Tags: python, excel, numpy, pandas, scipy

I frequently use Python (and occasionally Excel) to process and compare test data between multiple experiments. In some cases the data might be out of sync which makes direct comparisons difficult. For example, a typical test specification would be:

```
1) Stabilize test temperature to a value of 20 +/- 2 degrees C
2) Hold test temperature at stabilized value for 15-25 seconds
3) Increase temperature by 20 degrees C at a rate of 0.5 degree C/second
```

It is straightforward to normalize the data so they both start with a nominal temperature value of 20 C at time = 0 seconds, but what I really want is to synchronize the data so that the temperature ramps begin at the same time.

I've tried simple algorithms to check the slope of data to identify when the temperature increase begins, but local fluctuations in the measurements due to instrumentation result in slopes that don't actually reflect the overall rate of change in temperature.

Are there functions in Numpy, Scipy, Pandas, etc. that can filter out these local fluctuations and identify when the temperature actually begins to increase.

I do occasionally work in Excel so if there is a more convenient way to do this in a spreadsheet I can use Excel to process the data.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: couple ideas: (1) filter your data, convolution with G. kernel maybe enough,but play with kernel size. (2) try to make linear regression of your data; offset beginning of your regression, offset from which slope will be constant is beginning of your ramp.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand (2). I have experimented with linear regression however, since there is a 20-30 second hold after the maximum temperature is reached, the slope of the regression line did not seem to be meaningful. Does the method you're suggesting assume that the test is stopped after the 20 degree increased in reached?

Comment: well if you will use only part data for 15-20 sec for regression analysis, at data where you "Hold test temperature at stabilized value for 15-25 seconds" slope will be at the zero. Then it increases. when it reach your actual slope 0.5 C/sec, there is no tail of holding in regression data.... may be I don't understand your problem. Could you please to share an example?

Comment: How noisy is the data?  Can you post a typical sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this.  The first thing that comes to mind is to numerically differentiate the data, and look for the jump in the slope from 0 to 0.5.  But (as you observed) noisy data can prevent this from working well.  If you google for "numerical differentiation of noisy data", you'll find *a lot* of research on this topic, but I don't know of any off-the-shelf libraries in python.  You might be able to make some progress using a Savitzky-Golay filter: [`scipy.signal.savgol_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html).

However, that approach is probably overkill, since your signal has a very simple and specific expected structure:  a constant interval followed by a ramp and then another constant.  You might find that [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) works fine for this.  Here's an example:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def ramp(t, temp_init, temp_final, t0, t1):
    slope = (temp_final - temp_init) / (t1 - t0)
    y = temp_init + np.minimum(slope * np.maximum(t - t0, 0.0), temp_final - temp_init)
    return y

np.random.seed(123)

dt = 0.5
t = np.arange(0, 100, dt)

# Generate a sample to work with.
temp_init = 20.0 + np.random.randn()
temp_final = 40.0 + np.random.randn()
t0 = 25.0
t1 = t0 + 40
y = ramp(t, temp_init, temp_final, t0, t1)
y += 0.25*np.random.randn(*t.shape)  # Add noise.

# Create an initial guess for the four parameters and use curve_fit
# to fit the ramp function to the sample.
T = t[-1] - t[0]
p0 = (20, 40, t[0] + 0.333*T, t[0] + 0.667*T)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(ramp, t, y, p0=p0)
fit_temp_init, fit_temp_final, fit_t0, fit_t1 = popt


print "             Input    Fit"
print "temp_init   %6.2f  %6.2f" % (temp_init, fit_temp_init)
print "temp_final  %6.2f  %6.2f" % (temp_final, fit_temp_final)
print "t0          %6.2f  %6.2f" % (t0, fit_t0)
print "t1          %6.2f  %6.2f" % (t1, fit_t1)

plt.plot(t, y, 'ro', alpha=0.15)
plt.plot(t, ramp(t, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3]), 'k-', linewidth=1.5)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('t', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

This generates the output:

```
             Input    Fit
temp_init    18.91   18.91
temp_final   41.00   40.99
t0           25.00   24.85
t1           65.00   65.09
```

and the plot:

[image: fit ramp]